# Use count() in more than one column and order results

Tags: r, dataframe, count, na

I have a dataframe called `table` like this

```
      a  m  g     c1     c2     c3      c4 
1  2015  5 13  bread   wine   <NA>    <NA>    
2  2015  8 30   wine   eggs   rice    cake 
3  2015  1 21   wine   rice   eggs    <NA>       
...
```

I want to count the elements in column c1 to c4 and order them
I tried to use:

```
library(plyr)
c<-count(table,"c1")
```

But i don't know how to count more than one column.

Then i want to use `arrange(c,desc(freq))` to order them but when i try with one column the value NA is always on top, and i want only top 3 elements. Like this

```
     c  freq
1 wine     3
2 eggs     2
3 rice     2
```

Can someone please get me some solution for this. Thanks

Comment: How about `table(unlist(table[startsWith(names(table), "c")]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `melt` and `table`:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="a  m  g     c1     c2     c3      c4
2015  5 13  bread   wine   NA    NA
2015  8 30   wine   eggs   rice    cake
2015  1 21   wine   rice   eggs    NA", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

c_col <- melt(as.matrix(df1[,4:7]))
sort(table(c_col$value),decreasing=TRUE)

 wine  eggs  rice bread  cake 
    3     2     2     1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

With `qdaptools`, with the example dataframe (having name `table`) provided:

```
library(qdapTools)
counts <- data.frame(count=sort(colSums(mtabulate(table[,4:7])), decreasing=TRUE)) 
subset(counts,rownames(counts)!='<NA>')[1:3,1,drop=FALSE] #remove <NA>, select top 3 elements

#      count
# wine     3
# eggs     2
# rice     2
```